# A Trivial Pursuit #10 (Art and Literature 2/4): Bookshelf

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual, literature

<sub>This is part 10 of [A Trivial Pursuit](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a60644%20is%3aq%20%22a%20trivial%20pursuit%22&searchOn=3), a 25-part puzzle hunt. Each part is solvable on its own, with the exception of the meta-puzzle at the end.</sub>

---

[image: Bookshelf]
<sup>*Colourblind-friendly version available [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mitMD.png).*</sup>

**The answer is a short two-word phrase of six letters.**

<sub>*For accessibility, text on labelled book spines reads as follows, from left to right, by shelf:*</sub>

|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TBTM (2022) : RO | ASP (2010) : QB | OT (1838) : CD | DTD (2015) : MCB | TNOTR (1980) : UE | TS (1964) : WG |
| ()-- | ()--- | -()-- | --()- | -()-- | ---()- |
| CRSL | CMPNY | WCKD | RNT | HR | GRS |

<sup>*Shelves are labelled (from top to bottom): 'FICTION', '???' and 'MSCLS'.*</sup>

Comment: The purple ends with Pocket.

Comment: @1357924680a could you elaborate?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The top row is

> well, fiction - but more specifically, fictional books, with their titles and authors initialized:
>
>  **T**he **B**ullet **T**hat **M**issed (2022) : **R**ichard **O**sman
>  **A**ngelica **S**procket's **P**ockets (2010) : **Q**uentin **B**lake
>  **O**liver **T**wist (1838) : **C**harles **D**ickens
>  **D**ishing **T**he **D**irt (2015) : **M**.**C**. **B**eaton
>  **T**he **N**ame **O**f **T**he **R**ose (1980) : **U**mberto **E**co
>  **T**he **S**pire (1964) : **W**illiam **G**olding

Thanks to Davide (and Chrone, in comments) for finishing off the ones I couldn't figure out - check out [Davide's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/122444/77182) for more.

The bottom row is

> mscls wtht vwls - ahem, sorry, musicals without vowels:
>
>  Carousel
>  Company
>  Wicked
>  Rent
>  Hair
>  Grease

To figure out the middle row, we need to find

> synonyms of the musical names that can be found as reverse substrings in the corresponding novel, coded by color:
>
>  Rent -> RIP -> The S**pir**e
>  Wicked -> EVIL -> O**live**r Twist
>  Hair -> MANE -> Th**e Nam**e of the Rose
>  Carousel -> RIDE -> Dishing th**e Dir**t
>  Grease -> LUBE -> Th**e Bul**let That Missed
>  Company -> CORPS -> Angelica **Sproc**ket's Pockets

Now, looking at the letters marked with parentheses:

> **R**IP
>  **E**VIL
>  M**A**NE
>  RI**D**E
>  L**U**BE
>  COR**P**S

So, the final answer is (appropriately):

> **READ UP**!

Comment: I was starting to understand that from rot13(yhor) but you precedeed me, well done. I would have never found rot13(evc) tho, English is not my first language and while I'm quite proficient at it i would have never put on the same semantic level rot13(evc) and rot13(erag)

Comment: This is the correct final answer, well done. Re your 'quabble', this is the noun form not the past participle of the verb - see the synonyms in the 'opening, split' section [here](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/rent), for example :)

Comment: huh, don't think I've ever heard that word used that way - rot13(eraq) is much more common in my experience. I'll retract my quabble :)

Comment: Rent in the sense of rip or tear is very old English. The Bible is a good repository of its usage, and to this day, rending (ripping or tearing) your clothes is a Jewish way of expressing loss of a loved one (kriah). https://bible.knowing-jesus.com/words/Rent

Comment: @AlDante I'm familiar with rent as a past-tense verb (as the first few examples at your link all seem to use it), just not as a noun in the sense that Stiv describes above. this was probably more clear before I deleted the part in my answer that pretty much said exactly that

Comment: You are correct that most uses in that link are verb or adjective forms. Isa 3:24, and Matt 9:16 and Mrk 2:21 all show a noun form. Ezek 13:13 uses a form which I do not understand. 

Rent is not only a past tense. Mrk 9:26 is an example of its use in the present. 

I apologise that all the examples are biblical; it is just a very easy way to access older English usages.

Answer (score 6):

I managed to understand the first and third bookshelf

In the first we have a combination of TITLE (YEAR) : AUTHOR, for both the title and the author we only have the initials

> [image: First row]
> This is the result of the first row

Thanks to Chrone for completing the first row

I have no clue what the second row means

The title for the third row is then "Musicals", we only have some letters of the name of a musical in each of the covers.

> So for each word we have only the consonants and the rest has to be filled with vowels
>  [image: Third row]

Comment: I think “ASP (2010) : QB” is rot13(Natryvpn Fcebpxrg'f Cbpxrgf ol Dhragva Oynxr) and “DTD (2015) : MCB” might be rot13(Qvfuvat gur Qveg ol Z.P. Orngba).

Comment: Also one of the authors’ name is rot13(Evpuneq Bfzna abg Bfpnefba) and musical screenplays do come in the form of book. Not sure why you got downvoted, I think partial answer is allowed?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Puzzling! These are the right first steps to take (and Chrone is right that there is a typo in your answer as it stands) - keep going, and see if you can work out how to extract the answer :)

Comment: Perhaps you should line up the books against the musicals by colour and see whether / how they are connected. (Tip: start with Orange. And a fun fact: The titles on my German books read upwards, not downwards, so I alternate between tilting my head right and left when scanning my bookshelf, depending on whether the books are in English or in German.)